# Closing a pyplot window in wxpython with Ctrl-W causes a segmentation fault

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, exec

The graphical user interface to a programming/modeling environment I've created depends heavily on executing arbitrary python code from a wxwidgets gui. Below is a minimal, but typical example of how the GUI lets users create matplotlib graphs:

*UPDATE: Turns out, the bug doesn't rely on scripts being executed! See below*

```
import wx
script = """
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x ** 1.4
pl.figure()
pl.plot(x, y)
pl.show()
"""
class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__(None)
        button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Run')
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.action_run)
        self.Show()
    def action_run(self, e=None):
        exec(script)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Usually, the GUI would do a lot more than show just a run button, and the script is not static but entered by the user / read from a file. It works fine, on linux, mac and windows but...

If you close the figure using the mouse everything's ok. *If you close the figure with Ctrl-W the application crashes with a segfault.*

Does anybody have any ideas why this happens or how to debug this?

**Update:** here are the versions involved

```
>>> wx.version()
'wx.2.8.12.0 (gtk2-unicode)'
>>> mpl.__version__
'1.3.1'
```

The segfault occurs on linux (Fedora 20, Gnome 3.10.2)

**Versions:**

- Windows 7, Matplotlib 1.3.1, wxPython 2.8.12.1: no bug
- Fedora 20, Gnome 3.10.2, Matplotlib 1.3.1, wxPython 2.8.12.0: **bug**
- Fedora 20, Gnome 3.10.2, Matplotlib 1.4.2, wxPython 2.8.12.0: **bug**

**Update 2:**

It also happens without the script execution!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('wxAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__(None)
        button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, 'Run')
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.action_run)
        self.Show()
    def action_run(self, e=None):
        pl.figure()
        pl.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [3,1,2,5,4])
        pl.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a conflict between WxPython and Matplotlib trying to capture keyboard inputs. Have you tried binding a keyboard event in your WxPython application and filtering out the modifier keys?

Comment: I thought of that, but as far as I know WxPython doesn't do anything with Ctrl+W by default, and the crash occurs in the example code I gave, which doesn't add any Ctrl+W handling

Comment: No, I meant you could add a handler for those inputs that you have trouble with and try skipping and not skipping the event. Also, since you haven't posted the traceback, try other methods like calling the script as a thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm not sure what you mean. Adding a handler to the wx application doesn't capture anything, since it doesn't have focus when you're closing the matplotlib window with Ctrl-W. As for the traceback: It's a segfault, so I just go straight back to the console without any nice python error handling

Comment: I don't see a crash with wxPython 2.9 or 3.0.1 and mpl 1.4.0.  What default backend do you have configured?  Maybe add: matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

Comment: Thanks! I have tried specifying that in the main program and in the executed script, no difference though!

Comment: @Werner which OS are you using?

Comment: Ok, discovered I don't get this on a virtual machine running windows 7. Will submit a bug report! Workarounds are still very welcome.

Comment: @MichaelClerx, I am on Windows 8.1, so I see you get in Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I've added this information to the bug report at http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/16622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug :-/

Filed bug reports at:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3690

and

http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/16622

Comment: Hi Werner! I need it to work on the machines I distribute to, so I don't want to stray from the packages provided by (for example) fedora, ubuntu, pythonxy for windows etc. I was hoping someone could provide a workaround...

Comment: Hi Michael, understandable, but any chance you could test with the newer versions, if it works with them it might be easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Another thought, instead of using 'matplotlib.pyplot' use FigureCanvas and co - see the matplotlib example http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html

Comment: Thanks Werner. I'll try and rig up a virtual machine to test with newer versions. As for the embedding: that circumvents the Ctrl-W option entirely so it works, but for my application it's crucial that users can use the simple pyplot interface to quickly draw up some graphs!

Comment: Unable to get wxpython 3 running (it compiles and installs, but then can't find _core_). Still get the error in mpl 1.4 with wxpython 2.8 though